# CSS3 multiple background images from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background

How can one define multiple background images in CSS3 programmatically via JavaScript?

The obvious idea:

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('a.png') 0 100%, url('b.png') 50px 50px ";
```

doesn't work - it must be something simple, but what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`backgroundImage` is for background image only if you are setting multiple background properties in one you have to use `background`.

```
element.style.background = "url('a.png') 0 100%, url('b.png') 50px 50px ";
```