# multiple background images applied with js only applying first one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to apply multiple background images through element.style.background with js and only the first background is being applied. I know multiple backgrounds is supported because this is the latest chrome and when I apply it with css it works fine.

Here is what I am doing:

```
document.getElementById("box23").style.background="rgb(255, 255, 255) url(logo.svg) center left / 48px no-repeat, rgb(255, 255, 255) url(animation.gif) center right / contain no-repeat";
```

But it only applies the first background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317200/css3-multiple-background-images-from-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creates a CSS with the following class

```
.multi_bg_example {
  background-image: rgb(255, 255, 255) url(logo.svg),
                    rgb(255, 255, 255) url(animation.gif);

  background-repeat  : no-repeat,
                       no-repeat;

  background-position: center left,
                       center right;
}
```

then the javascrip:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("box23").addClass('multi_bg_example');
</script>
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, IMO.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Thanks I didn't think about doing it this way because for some reason I wanted to save on classes.

Answer (score 0):

This code, for example works for me:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.background = "url(http://goo.gl/PLN74m) left top/50% no-repeat, url(http://goo.gl/30JKDs) right top/50% no-repeat";
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/rbkz7jby/

I believe the problem could be in "center left" part, the order is messed up, it has to be "left center" I believe. Same goes with "center right".

Comment: I think, the problem is not in the `center left` part, but in the missing comma after the `rgb` parts.

Comment: Ah yeah, did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Stacking of the backgrounds is done from top to bottom, so you need `rgb(255, 255, 255)` to be the bottom most background. Also, `contain` isn't working in the shorthand. You can specify it using the `backgroundSize` property.

```js
var box23 = document.getElementById("box23");
box23.style.background="url(http://placehold.it/20x20) center left 48px no-repeat, \
                        url(http://placehold.it/40x40) center right 50px no-repeat, \
                        rgb(255, 255, 255)";
box23.style.backgroundSize="48px, contain";
```

```css
#box23 {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box23">
</div>
```